# Rails 2.3 routing namespace resources with custom variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Rails 2.3.11

So I have a namespace where I want to specify the 'path' for each item underneath it for example:

```
accounts.namespace(:accounts) do |f|
  f.resources :sub_accounts, :path => "sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account"
end
```

would generate:

```
GET     /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account index   
GET     /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account new 
POST    /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account create  
GET     /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account show    
GET     /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account edit    
PUT     /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account update  
DELETE  /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account destroy
```

I know you can do this with something like:

```
map.connect '/accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account', :controller => "accounts/sub_accounts", :action => "index"

GET     /accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account index
```

However the variables will be consistent across all routes in the accounts namespace and I didn't want to have to type all that out each time.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `path_prefix` option. This will prepend that path to your resources.

```
f.resources :sub_accounts, :path_prefix => 'sub_accounts'
```

Read more at the documentation for resources: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M002114

Comment: The problem here is that the resulting route is:
GET "/sub_accounts/sub_accounts/:id" SHOW

What I need is
/accounts/sub_accounts/:account_number/:sub_account

I'm not sure if there is a ":path_suffix" but that could hold ":sub_account" but the result is then:
/accounts/sub_accounts/:id/:sub_account

So I still haven't overwrote the :id variable in the url.